# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda python code called `lambda_function.py` and the handler name is set as `lambda_function.lambda_handler`.  However when I try to test I get the error:

> Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function

Any help advice would be greatly appreciated

[image: error]

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: 35e3129d-622c-421f-abbc-3818150a2042 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'
Traceback (most recent call last):
END RequestId: 35e3129d-622c-421f-abbc-3818150a2042
REPORT RequestId: 35e3129d-622c-421f-abbc-3818150a2042  Duration: 1.33 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB

Request ID
35e3129d-622c-421f-abbc-3818150a2042
```

Comment: please paste code so we could help

Comment: Your code is deployed wrong. The `lambda_function.py` is not in the "root" folder, but in `testFunction`. This won't work. Move `lambda_function.py` to the root folder. But then you will have other modules that can't be found. So I would start out small. Only have a single Python file, get that deployed and working, before you add all those dependencies.

Comment: root folder woukd be the pv-live-sourcecode folder?

Comment: @WindSwept No folder at all. Delete everything and just put your Python file in the Lambda.

Comment: I deleted all folder except for the testFunction folder and saved the python code in that folder.  But still get same error.

Comment: Finally got this work with the depandencies.  Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it.